# Java BufferedReader conversion loop hanging when reading from socket

Tags: java, http, parsing, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm writing a piece of software which connects an outside source (which I have near no control over) to a local database in Java via HTTP 1.0. I'm trying to return information from the database in the body of the response before the connection closes (the external source has a very lenient timeout schedule). I'm using a `BufferedReader` to read the stream from the socket, but most of the body (the only part we have control over) is being cut off before it can be read. A workaround that was figured out was adding two new lines (`\n`) to the body to force the data through, but I feel this may be working around a larger issue.

Is there an alternative to `BufferedReader` that signals when a socket has stopped writing to its buffer, or am I misusing `BufferedReader`? Some code:

Accepting the connection from the server:

```
HttpHandler(ServerSocket serverSocket, Executor service) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
{
    this.service = service;
    Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    InetAddress client = connectionSocket.getInetAddress();

    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
}
```

And processing the buffer into a string:

```
@Override
public String[] call() throws Exception 
{
    String output[] = new String[2];
    String line = new String();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while((line = input.readLine()) != null) //hangs here
    {
        if(line.startsWith("external-"))
        {
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }

    buffer = builder.toString();

    output = split(buffer);

    System.out.println("Process Request Complete");
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Are you remembering to flush your BufferedWriter?

Comment: Yes, this occurs after I send output.  Should it be happening sooner?

Comment: Is the data stream truly line-oriented (i.e. does it consist of lines separated by `\n`?  Does the LAST line end with `\n`?

Comment: Yes, it's line oriented, and the last line does end with a \n